# Any advantage to charging on charge card as detailed below?

Tags: credit-card

Is there any advantage to doing the following?:
I have cards A and B. Card A has some balance and its cycle date is 9th of the month. Card B is more of an emergency card. It has zero balance and it’s cycle date is on 23rd of the month. The intention is not to pay any interest on credit card by paying statement balance each month. Suppose I charged on card A until cycle date of card B begins on 23rd. Let’s say amount due in May would be $1800. From 23rd until 9th of next month, I would use card B . Say amount charged would be $1800 due in June. I would then use Card A again until Card B cycle ends on 23rd and charge $1100 due in June also. If I figured correctly, I would have to pay $1100 less in May then June. I would take some of that and apply towards the upcoming June bill. I’ll assume charges in the following month would be around same amount.To make long story short, is there any advantage to staggering charges on each of the cards this way or is it too complicated to try?

Comment: Perhaps adding what the expected / perceived advantage is to the question would help. Right now you're simply describing using two credit cards instead of one.

Comment: I believe another person has done answered as to what the advantage would be (longer credit period for expenditures). That was the perceived advantage to spending as described in the question. I was trying to see if I was looking at it the same way as someone else would.

Answer (score 1):

You would enjoy a longer credit period for your spends.

That means you have more cash in hand, given the bank rates are near zero; you may get few dollars more in interest.